# error: undefined reference while giving NDK build for application using openssl library

Tags: android-ndk, openssl, fips, ndk-build

I have followed [FIPS Library and Android](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/FIPS_Library_and_Android) from the OpenSSL wiki to build the FIPS Object Module. After creating `libcrypto.a` for both ARM and x86 architecture, I included `libcrypto.a` in my project's jni/include folder, and then performed an NDK build.

I am getting the below error everytime. Not able to resolve the issue. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong.

```
5.45/OpenSSL/jni/include/armeabi/libcrypto.a(fipscanister.o):fips_canister.c:function fips_openssl_cpuid_setup: error: undefined reference to 'sigfillset'
5.45/OpenSSL/jni/include/armeabi/libcrypto.a(fipscanister.o):fips_canister.c:function fips_openssl_cpuid_setup: error: undefined reference to 'sigdelset'
5.45/OpenSSL/jni/include/armeabi/libcrypto.a(fipscanister.o):fips_canister.c:function fips_openssl_cpuid_setup: error: undefined reference to 'sigdelset'
5.45/OpenSSL/jni/include/armeabi/libcrypto.a(fipscanister.o):fips_canister.c:function fips_openssl_cpuid_setup: error: undefined reference to 'sigdelset'
5.45/OpenSSL/jni/include/armeabi/libcrypto.a(fipscanister.o):fips_canister.c:function fips_openssl_cpuid_setup: error: undefined reference to 'sigdelset'
5.45/OpenSSL/jni/include/armeabi/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:function read_string_inner: error: undefined reference to 'signal'
5.45/OpenSSL/jni/include/armeabi/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:function read_string_inner: error: undefined reference to 'tcsetattr'
5.45/OpenSSL/jni/include/armeabi/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:function read_string_inner: error: undefined reference to 'tcsetattr'
5.45/OpenSSL/jni/include/armeabi/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:function open_console: error: undefined reference to 'tcgetattr'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [5.45/OpenSSL/obj/local/armeabi/libmaascrypto.so] Error 1
```

Here is the Android.mk inside my NDK_application/jni folder

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := crypto
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := include/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libcrypto.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := XYZcrypto
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := XYZcbcEncryption.cpp XYZEcbEncryption.cpp XYZSHA256.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := crypto
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: What version of the Android OS are you running on your device, and what API level are you building for?

Comment: I am building for API level 23. And I have not pushed it to my device yet. This error I am getting when giving NDK build using the command "$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/ndk-build"

Comment: It looks like you are missing some libraries. Add your `Android.mk` so we can see what libraries you are linking in addition to `libcrypto.a`.

Comment: I have updated my post with the content of my Android.mk

Comment: Any luck with this @Sanjib ?